# Parse iOS Download has huge Binary

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I was trying to create an IPA in XCode6 that use the Parse IOS SDK. While my app is very simple, the App size came out to 46MB!!. Upon investigation I found a file called "Parse" inside the Parse.Framework bundle (visible in Finder but not in XCode) which as 32M in size, so its clear the large file size is due to Parse.

I tried making the architectures as armv7, still the file size is 44M.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you add the Parse SDK to your project? Did you use Cocoapods?

Comment: Did you inspect an IPA or just your project? Inspect an IPA  (i.e. Export your app to the desktop and unzip it) and it can pinpoint exactly what file is the culprit.

Comment: @Russell I followed the documentation (Quick Start) to add the library. Essentially it was a drag and then a tick to "copy files if needed"

Comment: @soulshined I unchecked the "Use Bit Code" in settings and that reduced the file size to 27M. Some links on googling show that with Xcode 7 the upload size is huge even though the final binary from app store will be smaller. I have submitted the 27M binary, will update based on the response I get.